# Silly C++ linking trouble in GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, pragma

Sorry for the non-specific question title. On short, here's what I have:

**file1.cpp**

```
#include "file1.h"

int main()
{
    somefunc();
}
```

**file1.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "file2.h"

int somevar;
```

**file2.cpp**

```
#include "file2.h"

void somefunc()
{}
```

**file2.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "file1.h"

void somefunc();
```

This compiles well with GCC but gives me '`multiple definition of somevar`' during linking.

What is wrong?

Comment: it may gives compiler error when you remove #pragma once

Comment: @Aryabhata Unrelated.

Answer (score 2):

You are defining `somevar` in multiple files by including the header file containing its definition into more than one .cpp file. Declare it as `extern int somevar;` in the header, and only define it in exactly one .cpp file.

Comment: I thought `#pragma once` or prehaps include guards would do the trick.

Comment: @PetruDimitriu You're misunderstanding what `#pragma once` and include guards do. They prevent you from including the same header file multiple times ***into the same translation unit*** (.cpp file). They don't, can't and shouldn't prevent you from including it into multiple **different** .cpp files, which is causing the problem in this case.

Comment: But what if I have some dozens of cpp's and h's that depend on each other and declaring `extern` only makes things worse?

Comment: @PetruDimitriu You still include the header file. But you inly have `extern int somevar;` in the header. You have `int somevar;` in **one** cpp file only.